# Dying vinca plant

Tags: container-gardening

[image][image]How to save my dying vinca plant? I attached photos.Please help me.[image]. I am from Mumbai.I brought this plant from local nursery 7 days ago, I use vermicompost. I used to keep outdoor usually. I used normal gardening soil.

Comment: You should give us some more information: how old it is the plant? Did you fertilize it? (how much? how many times?) How do you water it? BTW the photo is very dark. Could you make new better photos?

Comment: If you don't have the label with the plant name, please add another photo taken in good light and in focus - under magnification, the one you've posted is blurry so it cannot be seen clearly, unfortunately.  Do you keep it outdoors usually? Have you recently repotted it and what soil did you use? And where are you in the world?

Comment: I am from Mumbai , India. I added another photo . I usually keep outdoor. I brought this plant from local nursery 7 days ago, I used normal gardening soil, using vermi compost to this plant. I watered very less to this plant, still plant dying slowly. All flowering plant has the same issue. Please help.

Comment: Just for clarification: did you use *garden* soil (so a shovel full of what you have in your garden) or *gardening* soil from a bag?

Comment: @Sunild, when you say outdoor, do you mean to say that you had been keeping it under direct sunlight?

Comment: Not direct sunlight near the window. Only 5 hours sunlight is there.

Answer (score 1):

Your plant appears to be Catharansus roseus, commonly known as Madagascar Periwinkle, also frequently confusingly referred to as vinca, which it isn't, Vinca is a separate genus. It does not tolerate frost and is therefore grown  as an annual in colder parts of the world.

Couple of things - this plant does not appreciate soil which is richly fertile, so adding vermicompost won't have done it much good. It does better in the ground outdoors in partial or dappled shade, in ordinary garden soil  which has not been over fertilized.  Sterilised potting soil should be used if you want to grow it in a pot, but I understand, where  you are, that can be difficult to source. Using garden soil in pots is not really recommended because there may be pathogens within it which, whilst fine in open ground, are not fine when confined to a pot, or at least, not fine for any plant trying to grow in the pot. As a side comment, the pot has also been overfilled - the soil within should leave half to one inch clear at the top to facilitate watering; if the soil is right to the top, water just runs off and the plant may suffer drought. The pot should also have drainage holes,and should never be left sitting in water in any outer tray or pot.

If it's still alive, it would be better to transfer it either to a pot with proper potting soil (and don't fill the pot to the top) or find a spot for it outdoors - keep it watered after planting. Further information here https://worldoffloweringplants.com/grow-care-madagascar-periwinkle-catharanthus-roseus/

Comment: Right, it looks like the missing part at the rim is even lower than the soil itself. All the water would probably run down from that hole, rather than penetrating the soil.